# Calculate the maximum difference in rolling pandas - improve performance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with one column.

I need to calculate the **average** of the **difference** between the **min and max values** over 600 seconds period (10 minutes). Or more clearly this :

```
np.average(originalData[sensor1].rolling(600)
.apply(lambda mylist : (max(mylist) - min(mylist)), raw = True).dropna())
```

The code works perfectly and returns me the results I need.

The problem is that my Dataframe is pretty large (1.5 million lines, and 200 columns), and it takes a lot of time, specially if I want to go from 600 seconds to 3600 second.

I want to improve it by not to calculating the difference on every row, but by skipping 10 rows each time, it shouldn't impact the results significantly.

Meaning :

- Calculate max(list)-min(list) on row 0 to 600
- Calculate max(list)-min(list) on row 10 to 610
- Calculate max(list)-min(list) on row 20 to 620
- Calculate max(list)-min(list) on row 30 to 630

This will speed up the calculation 10 times (hopefully), but I don't see how I can do it with `rolling`

Any suggestions ?

**Edit:**
muzzyq requested sample data :

```
a = np.ones(1500000)
np.average(pd.Series(a).rolling(600).
apply(lambda thing : (max(thing) - min(thing)), raw = True).dropna())
```

Comment: Do you have any sample data?

Comment: @muzzyq, I'm using an array of ones for performance testing

Comment: any luck using `resample`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resample` method with `'10min'` as argument to group by 10 minute intervals. It is more efficient than using `rolling` for large sets of time series data, assuming it is set as the index.

### Sample data

```
rng = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=1_500_000, freq='S')
ts = pd.Series(np.arange(1_500_000), index=rng)
ts.head()
```

Output:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
2000-01-01 00:00:01    1
2000-01-01 00:00:02    2
2000-01-01 00:00:03    3
2000-01-01 00:00:04    4
Freq: S, dtype: int64
```

### Answer

Using the function from your question:

```
np.average(ts.resample('10min').apply(lambda mylist: (max(mylist) - min(mylist))))
```

Output:

```
599.0
```

#### Alternative

Just because I'm not 100% sure what you want the outcome to look like, this will give you the range per 10 minute interval:

```
result = ts.resample('10min').apply(lambda mylist: (max(mylist) - min(mylist)))
result.head()
```

Output:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    599
2000-01-01 00:10:00    599
2000-01-01 00:20:00    599
2000-01-01 00:30:00    599
2000-01-01 00:40:00    599
Freq: 10T, dtype: int64
```

In this case, the answer will always be 599 as the maximum of 600 seconds is 600 and the minimum is 1, so `600 - 1 = 599`